# Exception Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to cache a sitemap generated from a controller for a website that I am working on, but apparently I am doing something wrong, as I don't understand the Error message.
Here is the code snippet causing the trouble (it is a controller Method). Everything works correctly until I add the caching.

```
public function mapContent($type, Request $request)
{
    $cachingKey = $request->fullUrl();

    if ($type !== 'news' && $type !== 'pages') {
        abort(404);
    } elseif (Cache::has($cachingKey)) {
        $items = Cache::get($cachingKey);

    } else {

        $items = $this->_getElementsSitemap($type);
        Cache::put($cachingKey, $items, now()->addDays(7));

    }

    return Response::make($items, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `$items = $this->_getElementsSitemap($type);` returns not serializable instance.

Your class should implement [`__serialize`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.serialize) method